# How do I combine 2 SELECT statements where the result

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How do I combine 2 SELECT statements where the result of the first select is used in the WHERE of the second SELECT

Below is the code I am using right now:

```
$order_id = 7655;

$first  = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_ticket_order' AND meta_value = %d", $order_id ) );

if ( $first ) {
  $second = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_ticket_event' AND post_id = %d", $first ) );
}

echo $second;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a join between the two queries

```
$second = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT b.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta a 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id 
WHERE a.meta_key = '_ticket_order' AND a.meta_value = %d", $order_id ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. I got the result I needed by making some modifications to your code.

`$second = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT b.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta a INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
                                                    WHERE a.meta_key = '_ticket_order' AND a.meta_value = %d AND b.meta_key = '_ticket_event'", $order_id ) );`